# Show that $\lVert Ax \rVert \geq \lVert x \rVert \lVert A^{-1} \rVert^{-1}$ where $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a vector induced norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-calculus, matrix-norms

I want to prove that $$\lVert Ax \rVert \geq \lVert x \rVert  \lVert A^{-1} \rVert^{-1}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible, and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a vector induced matrix norm, defined as
$$\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{x\neq0}{\lVert Ax \rVert \over \lVert x \rVert}$$
(that obeys $\lVert A B \rVert \leq  \lVert A \rVert\lVert B \rVert$).

I know that $\lVert Ax \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert  \lVert A \rVert$ (which follows from the definition of $\lVert A \rVert$) and that $1 \leq \lVert A \rVert \lVert A^{-1} \rVert$. I have tried manipulating the latter and even trying to apply the definition of $\lVert A \rVert$ in proving this inequality, but to no success.

Any help?

Comment: But what is your definition of $\|A\|$, more precisely $\|A\|_{p}$? also include these efforts in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following :
$$
\|x\|_{2}=\|A^{-1}Ax\|_{2}
\implies
\|x\|_{2}=\frac{\|A^{-1}Ax\|_{2}}{\|Ax\|_{2}}\|Ax\|_{2}
$$
The latter expression implies that since $Ax\in\operatorname{Im}(A)$ then there shall be a vector $y\neq0$ such that
$$
\|x\|_{2}\leq\max_{y\neq0}\frac{\|A^{-1}y\|_{2}}{\|y\|_{2}}\|Ax\|_{2}=\|A^{-1}\|_{2}\|Ax\|_{2}
$$
Therefore you end up with :
$$
\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}_{2}\|x\|_{2}\leq\|Ax\|_{2}
$$
Note that I am assuming you are using the following definition of $\|A\|_{p}$
$$
\|A\|_{p}=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{p}}{\|x\|_{p}}=\max_{\|x\|_{p}=1}\|Ax\|_{p}
$$
A matrix norm sub-ordinate or induced by a vector norm.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for any matrix $A$ and vector $x$,  $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|$ (this should be straight forward to prove).

Now using $A^{-1}$ instead of $A$ and $Ax$ instead of $x$ we have have $\|A^{-1}(Ax)\| \leq \ \|A^{-1}\|\|Ax\|$ or in other words $\|x\| \leq \|A^{-1}\| \|Ax\|$. Multiplying by $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ yields your inequality.